# ICU ResourceBundle arguments

Tags: c++, resourcebundle, icu

I'm using the ResourceBundle at ICU library with c/C++.

I do a test with simple messages and works fine.

Now I'm trying to use messages with arguments, for example:

error{"Error: {0}"}

Is there any way to get the resource and check if it has arguments to use the FormatString class ?

For example in the resource:

error{"Error: {0}"}

Is a method to get the number of arguments ? In this case one.

Thanks

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. One of the differences is C has no classes. Please pick the tag appropriate for your problem. Oh, and please clarify your problem. `error{"Error: {0}"}` is neither C nor C++.

Comment: Thanks for hints Olaf.. I try to explain better at question.